# on IE11, the letter type list (list-style-type: lower-alpha) has lost indentation

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-11

on IE11, the letter type list (list-style-type: lower-alpha) has lost indentation. It retains indentation on chrome, edge, and firefox. Below is the code that shows some of the CSS used.

```css
body {
  background: none;
  font: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  border-left: none;
  width: 600;
}

.container p {
  margin: 10px 0
}

#redbox {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#redbox p {
  color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.bigger {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media print {
  body {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ol class='margin'>
  <li><strong>Definitions.</strong>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Affiliate&rdquo;</strong> means any entity and its successors which directly or indirectly controls, is controlled by, or is under common control with the subject entity. <strong>&ldquo;Control&rdquo;</strong> for purposes of this
        definition, means direct or indirect ownership or control of more than 50% of the voting interests of the subject entity. An entity shall be considered an Affiliate only so long as such entity continues to meet the foregoing definition.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Agreement&rdquo;</strong> means this End User License Agreement (<strong>&ldquo;EULA&rdquo;</strong>) together with a SKU or associated SSLA (if any), License Entitlement (if any), Product Warranty Policy, and any other documents,
        policies or website content linked in this EULA and hereby incorporated by reference.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Approved Source&rdquo;</strong> means Juniper or an Authorized Reseller.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Authorized Reseller&rdquo;</strong>means a distributor or reseller authorized by Juniper to distribute and resell licenses to the Software in the territory in which You are purchasing such Software license.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Commercial Cloud Services&rdquo;</strong> means a service offered and administered by Juniper, or an authorized third party, whereby You may without downloading or otherwise taking delivery of a copy of the Software use and access
        Instances of Software running in a virtual machine environment resident in a networked cloud facility or group of facilities.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Embedded Software License&rdquo;</strong> means the limited right to Use the operating system Software installed on the Juniper Platform and included in the purchase of the Juniper Platform but does not include the right to Use the
        Separately Licensable Features and may not be Used on more than the number of ports, if any, identified in the SKU or associated SSLA (if any) for the Juniper Platform. Embedded Software Licenses are Perpetual unless the Juniper hardware is leased
        or provided for demonstration purposes, in which case the Embedded Software License term shall follow the lease term or demonstration period and shall terminate automatically upon the expiration of the lease term or demonstration period.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Feature Set License&rdquo;</strong> means the limited right to Use solely the certain set of features and functionalities of the Software as described in the License Entitlement and SKU or associated SSLA (if any), regardless of whether
        any additional feature or functionality is unlocked and thus accessible to You in the Software. Feature Set Licenses may also be combined with other Juniper Software licenses.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Instance&rdquo;</strong> means each time the Software runs on any device.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Juniper Networks&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;Juniper&rdquo;</strong> means: (a) Juniper Networks (US), Inc. if Products and/or Services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in North America, Central America or South America;
        (b) Juniper Networks International B.V., if products and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in Europe (excluding the United Kingdom), the Middle East or Africa; or the Asia Pacific region (excluding Australia and India), (c)
        Juniper Networks (UK) Limited if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in the United Kingdom, (d) Juniper Networks Australia Pty Ltd if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in Australia, or
        (e) Juniper Networks Solution India Private Limited if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in India; and in each case, any Juniper Affiliate of the applicable Juniper Networks entity to whom this Agreement may be assigned.&nbsp;
        As used in connection with the provision of Services, the term &ldquo;Juniper Networks&rdquo; or &ldquo;Juniper&rdquo; under this Agreement may include authorized services representatives of Juniper.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Juniper Platform&rdquo;</strong> means any Juniper-provided, but not any third-party-provided, hardware.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Entitlement&rdquo;</strong> means the email document that includes the License Term, SKU or associated SSLA (if any), License Metric and Licensed Units (if any) found in the Model Description.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Metric&rdquo;</strong> means a unit of measurement that restricts the scope of use of the Software (e.g., Feature Set License, Instance, Network Element or Node, Session Socket or CPU Socket or Throughput or any other unit
        of measurement set forth in a SKU or associated SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement).</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Term&rdquo;</strong> means the period of time that the Software is licensed to be Used by You, subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Licensed Units&rdquo;</strong> mean a number of units under a License Metric that limits the Use of the licensed Software (e.g. 10M, 50 Nodes, 1000 Sessions or any other units under a License Metric set forth in a SKU or associated
        SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement).</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Maintenance Services&rdquo;</strong> means those services described in Section 6 below.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Model Description&rdquo;</strong> means a field in the License Entitlement that will denote the applicable License Metric and maximum Licensed Units (if any), and, if a Subscription, the period of time that shall be the fixed term.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Network Element&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;Node&rdquo;</strong> means a physical or virtual device that is recognizable by the Software as a unique device that the Software may directly or indirectly administer, monitor, manage,
        provision, or configure.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Perpetual&rdquo;</strong> license means a license that continues until the first to occur of termination by Juniper or Your violation of any term or condition of this Agreement, unless such violation is waived in writing by Juniper.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Separately Licensable Features&rdquo;</strong> means specific features and functionalities of the Software that may only be Used if a Feature Set License is obtained and such features and functionalities are expressly set forth in
        a SKU or associated SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Session&rdquo;</strong> means a stateful information exchange connection established for communication between two devices through a gateway.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;SKU&rdquo;</strong> means a stock-keeping unit or unique identifier for each distinct product and service that can be purchased and any summary description of such product or service associated therewith.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Socket&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;CPU Socket&rdquo;</strong> means a mechanical component that provides electrical connectivity between a microprocessor and a printed circuit board.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Software&rdquo;</strong> means the software product and version number that is either identified in Your License Entitlement or licensed pursuant to the Embedded Software License, and includes 1) machine-readable instructions and
        data, 2) components, files, and modules, 3) any accompanying audio-visual content, 4) accompanying activation keys, if any, and 5) associated documentation. Except where the context otherwise requires, Software includes any Update of that Software
        that You are entitled to through Maintenance Services.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Software Specific License Addendum&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;SSLA&rdquo;</strong> means the additional terms and conditions (if any), applicable to certain Software, which may be found at <a href="https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/licenses/ssla/software-specific-license-addenda.html">https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/licenses/ssla/software-specific-license-addenda.html</a>.
        SSLAs (if any) are referenced in the License Entitlement and/or SKU. If there is any conflict between the SSLA and this EULA, the SSLA shall take precedence with respect to the specific Software to which it pertains.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Subscription&rdquo;</strong> license means a license to Use the Software with accompanying Maintenance Services solely during a fixed Subscription Term, unless terminated earlier by Juniper pursuant to the terms and conditions of
        this Agreement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Subscription Term&rdquo;</strong> means the duration of time that a Subscription is active.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Throughput&rdquo;</strong> means the maximum possible bits of inbound data traffic capable of being processed per second by an Instance of Software. A Throughput license may not be split across multiple Instances. Throughput licenses
        will be identified in the SKU Description and License Entitlement in units of megabits per second (Mbps or M), gigabits per second (Gbps or G), or terabits per second (Tbps or T). In the event Juniper Software supports bursts, the actual Throughput
        must not exceed the licensed Throughput more than 5% of the time across any arbitrary set of five (5) minute sample intervals during the License Term.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Update&rdquo;</strong> is defined in the Service Description Document that pertains to the Maintenance Services purchased or included with the Software, as applicable.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Use&rdquo;</strong> means to install, utilize, access, activate, or view the Software in executable form.</li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. When I open that in IE11 it looks the same as it does in Chrome. Does that snippet reproduce the issue for you?

Comment: Hi there, in IE11, there is no indentation. In Chrome and edge and firefox it shows correct indentation.

Comment: I played with the code and figured it out myself:   ...........................................To render the numbers in the problematic IE11 browser, I had to change the .container width:auto to width: 600 in the style section at the top.

                                .container {border-left: none; width: 600;}
                            
                             
To force the indentation on IE11, I had to add margin-left:10px; in the OL style tags…all of them

<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha; margin-left:10px;">

Comment: hmm that sounds good, but you're providing indentation through margin there. It doesn't explain why your IE didn't provide indentation to begin with. Still someone facing a similar issue may certainly benefit from it. Can you post that as an answer? You can copy the snippet from the question and modify that to show how it should be. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I knew why, but all I know is that when I changed the .container width:auto to width: 600 in the style section at the top, the letters rendered. Ill post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I played with the code and figured it out myself: ...........................................To render the numbers in the problematic IE11 browser, I had to change the .container width:auto to width: 600 in the style section at the top. .container {border-left: none; width: 600;} To force the indentation on IE11, I had to add margin-left:10px; in the OL style tags…all of them

```
body {
  background: none;
  font: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  border-left: none;
  width: 600;
}

.container p {
  margin: 10px 0
}

#redbox {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#redbox p {
  color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#date {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.bigger {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media print {
  body {
    width: auto;
  }
}

<ol class='margin'>
  <li><strong>Definitions.</strong>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Affiliate&rdquo;</strong> means any entity and its successors which directly or indirectly controls, is controlled by, or is under common control with the subject entity. <strong>&ldquo;Control&rdquo;</strong> for purposes of this
        definition, means direct or indirect ownership or control of more than 50% of the voting interests of the subject entity. An entity shall be considered an Affiliate only so long as such entity continues to meet the foregoing definition.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Agreement&rdquo;</strong> means this End User License Agreement (<strong>&ldquo;EULA&rdquo;</strong>) together with a SKU or associated SSLA (if any), License Entitlement (if any), Product Warranty Policy, and any other documents,
        policies or website content linked in this EULA and hereby incorporated by reference.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Approved Source&rdquo;</strong> means Juniper or an Authorized Reseller.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Authorized Reseller&rdquo;</strong>means a distributor or reseller authorized by Juniper to distribute and resell licenses to the Software in the territory in which You are purchasing such Software license.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Commercial Cloud Services&rdquo;</strong> means a service offered and administered by Juniper, or an authorized third party, whereby You may without downloading or otherwise taking delivery of a copy of the Software use and access
        Instances of Software running in a virtual machine environment resident in a networked cloud facility or group of facilities.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Embedded Software License&rdquo;</strong> means the limited right to Use the operating system Software installed on the Juniper Platform and included in the purchase of the Juniper Platform but does not include the right to Use the
        Separately Licensable Features and may not be Used on more than the number of ports, if any, identified in the SKU or associated SSLA (if any) for the Juniper Platform. Embedded Software Licenses are Perpetual unless the Juniper hardware is leased
        or provided for demonstration purposes, in which case the Embedded Software License term shall follow the lease term or demonstration period and shall terminate automatically upon the expiration of the lease term or demonstration period.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Feature Set License&rdquo;</strong> means the limited right to Use solely the certain set of features and functionalities of the Software as described in the License Entitlement and SKU or associated SSLA (if any), regardless of whether
        any additional feature or functionality is unlocked and thus accessible to You in the Software. Feature Set Licenses may also be combined with other Juniper Software licenses.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Instance&rdquo;</strong> means each time the Software runs on any device.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Juniper Networks&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;Juniper&rdquo;</strong> means: (a) Juniper Networks (US), Inc. if Products and/or Services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in North America, Central America or South America;
        (b) Juniper Networks International B.V., if products and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in Europe (excluding the United Kingdom), the Middle East or Africa; or the Asia Pacific region (excluding Australia and India), (c)
        Juniper Networks (UK) Limited if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in the United Kingdom, (d) Juniper Networks Australia Pty Ltd if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in Australia, or
        (e) Juniper Networks Solution India Private Limited if product and/or services will be shipped to, deployed or rendered in India; and in each case, any Juniper Affiliate of the applicable Juniper Networks entity to whom this Agreement may be assigned.&nbsp;
        As used in connection with the provision of Services, the term &ldquo;Juniper Networks&rdquo; or &ldquo;Juniper&rdquo; under this Agreement may include authorized services representatives of Juniper.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Juniper Platform&rdquo;</strong> means any Juniper-provided, but not any third-party-provided, hardware.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Entitlement&rdquo;</strong> means the email document that includes the License Term, SKU or associated SSLA (if any), License Metric and Licensed Units (if any) found in the Model Description.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Metric&rdquo;</strong> means a unit of measurement that restricts the scope of use of the Software (e.g., Feature Set License, Instance, Network Element or Node, Session Socket or CPU Socket or Throughput or any other unit
        of measurement set forth in a SKU or associated SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement).</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;License Term&rdquo;</strong> means the period of time that the Software is licensed to be Used by You, subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Licensed Units&rdquo;</strong> mean a number of units under a License Metric that limits the Use of the licensed Software (e.g. 10M, 50 Nodes, 1000 Sessions or any other units under a License Metric set forth in a SKU or associated
        SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement).</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Maintenance Services&rdquo;</strong> means those services described in Section 6 below.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Model Description&rdquo;</strong> means a field in the License Entitlement that will denote the applicable License Metric and maximum Licensed Units (if any), and, if a Subscription, the period of time that shall be the fixed term.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Network Element&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;Node&rdquo;</strong> means a physical or virtual device that is recognizable by the Software as a unique device that the Software may directly or indirectly administer, monitor, manage,
        provision, or configure.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Perpetual&rdquo;</strong> license means a license that continues until the first to occur of termination by Juniper or Your violation of any term or condition of this Agreement, unless such violation is waived in writing by Juniper.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Separately Licensable Features&rdquo;</strong> means specific features and functionalities of the Software that may only be Used if a Feature Set License is obtained and such features and functionalities are expressly set forth in
        a SKU or associated SSLA (if any) or License Entitlement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Session&rdquo;</strong> means a stateful information exchange connection established for communication between two devices through a gateway.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;SKU&rdquo;</strong> means a stock-keeping unit or unique identifier for each distinct product and service that can be purchased and any summary description of such product or service associated therewith.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Socket&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;CPU Socket&rdquo;</strong> means a mechanical component that provides electrical connectivity between a microprocessor and a printed circuit board.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Software&rdquo;</strong> means the software product and version number that is either identified in Your License Entitlement or licensed pursuant to the Embedded Software License, and includes 1) machine-readable instructions and
        data, 2) components, files, and modules, 3) any accompanying audio-visual content, 4) accompanying activation keys, if any, and 5) associated documentation. Except where the context otherwise requires, Software includes any Update of that Software
        that You are entitled to through Maintenance Services.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Software Specific License Addendum&rdquo;</strong> or <strong>&ldquo;SSLA&rdquo;</strong> means the additional terms and conditions (if any), applicable to certain Software, which may be found at <a href="https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/licenses/ssla/software-specific-license-addenda.html">https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/licenses/ssla/software-specific-license-addenda.html</a>.
        SSLAs (if any) are referenced in the License Entitlement and/or SKU. If there is any conflict between the SSLA and this EULA, the SSLA shall take precedence with respect to the specific Software to which it pertains.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Subscription&rdquo;</strong> license means a license to Use the Software with accompanying Maintenance Services solely during a fixed Subscription Term, unless terminated earlier by Juniper pursuant to the terms and conditions of
        this Agreement.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Subscription Term&rdquo;</strong> means the duration of time that a Subscription is active.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Throughput&rdquo;</strong> means the maximum possible bits of inbound data traffic capable of being processed per second by an Instance of Software. A Throughput license may not be split across multiple Instances. Throughput licenses
        will be identified in the SKU Description and License Entitlement in units of megabits per second (Mbps or M), gigabits per second (Gbps or G), or terabits per second (Tbps or T). In the event Juniper Software supports bursts, the actual Throughput
        must not exceed the licensed Throughput more than 5% of the time across any arbitrary set of five (5) minute sample intervals during the License Term.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Update&rdquo;</strong> is defined in the Service Description Document that pertains to the Maintenance Services purchased or included with the Software, as applicable.</li>
      <li><strong>&ldquo;Use&rdquo;</strong> means to install, utilize, access, activate, or view the Software in executable form.</li>
    </ol>
```